# Is There a Way to Cause Powershell to Use a Particular Format for a Function's Output?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, output-formatting

I wish to *suggest* (perhaps *enforce*, but I am not firm on the semantics yet) a particular format for the output of a PowerShell function.

[about_Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.1) (versioned for PowerShell 7.1) says this: '*Beginning in PowerShell 6, the default views are defined in PowerShell source code. The Format.ps1xml files from PowerShell 5.1 and earlier versions don't exist in PowerShell 6 and later versions.*'. The article then goes on to explain how Format.ps1xml files can be used to change the display of objects, etc etc. This is not very explicit: **'don't exist' -ne 'cannot exist'...**

This begs several questions:

1. Although they 'don't exist', can Format.ps1xml files be created/used in versions of PowerShell greater than 5.1?
2. Whether they can or not, is there some better practice for suggesting to PowerShell how a certain function should format returned data? Note that inherent in 'suggest' is that **the pipeline nature of PowerShell's output must be preserved**: the user must still be able to pipe the output of the function to Format-List or ForEach-Object etc..

For example, the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet returns objects formatted by `Format-List`. If I write a function called `Search-ADUser` that calls `Get-ADUser` internally and returns some of those objects, the output will also be formatted as a list. Piping the output to `Format-Table` before returning it does not satisfy my requirements, because the output will then not be treated as separate objects in a pipeline.

Example code:

```
function Search-ADUser {
  param (
    $Name,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string[]]$Properties = @('Enabled', 'SamAccountName', 'Name', 'emailAddress', 'proxyAddresses')
  )
  return Get-ADUser -Filter ('name -like "*{0}*"' -F $Name) -Properties $Properties | Select-Object $Properties
}
```

The best answers should address both questions, although the second is more salient.

Unacceptable answers include suggestions that the function *should not* enforce a format, and/or that the user should pipe the output of the function to their formatter of choice. That is a very subjective stance, and whether it is held by the majority or not is irrelevant to the question.

I searched `force function format #powershell-7.0` before posting, but none of the search results appeared to be relevant.

Comment: With a very quick test I was able to create a new format definition for 'process' objects and import this into PS v7.1.3 using `Update-FormatData`, so it seems these files are still supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Although they 'don't exist', can `Format.ps1xml` files be created/used in versions of PowerShell greater than 5.1?

- Yes; in fact any *third-party* code *must* use them to define custom formatting.

  - That `*.ps1xml` *files* are invariably needed for such definitions is unfortunate; [GitHub issue #7845](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7845) asks for an in-memory, API-based alternative (which for *type* data already exists, via the [`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata) cmdlet).
  - However, in the context of [*modules*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), the need for files is less inconvenient, as they can be bundled with the module and are automatically loaded when referenced from the [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests)'s `FormatsToProcess` entry.
- It is only the formatting data that *ships with PowerShell* that is now hardcoded into the PowerShell (Core) executable, presumably for performance reasons.

> is there some better practice for suggesting to PowerShell how a certain function should format returned data?

The lack of an API-based way to define formatting data requires the following approach:

- Determine the full name of the .NET type(s) to which the formatting should apply.

  - If it is `[pscustomobject]` instances that the formatting should apply to, you need to (a) *choose* a unique (virtual) type name and (b) assign it to the `[pscustomobject]` instances via PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Types.ps1xml); e.g.:

    - For `[pscustomobject]` instances created by the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet:

      ```
      # Assign virtual type name "MyVirtualType" to the objects output
      # by Select-Object
      Get-ChildItem *.txt | Select-Object Name, Length | ForEach-Object {
        $_.pstypenames.Insert(0, 'MyVirtualType'); $_
      }
      ```
    - For `[pscustomobject]` *literals*, specify the type name via a `PSTypeName` entry:

      ```
      [pscustomobject] @{
        PSTypeName = 'MyVirtualType'
        foo = 1
        bar = 2
      }
      ```
- Create a `*.ps1mxl` file for that type and load it into every session.

  - If the commands that rely on this formatting data are defined in a *module*, you can incorporate the file into your module so that it is automatically automatically when the module is imported.
  - For help on authoring such files, see:

    - [Formatting File Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview)
    - [Format XML Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/format-schema-xml-reference)

[GitHub proposal #10463](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10463) asks for a greatly simplified experience, along the lines of supporting extended `[OutputType()]` attributes that specify the desired formatting.

---

**Applied to your sample function**:

- The following function creates a (temporary) `*.ps1xml` file for its output type *on demand*, on the first call in the session, so as to ensure that (implicit) `Format-Table` formatting is applied, for all 5 properties (by default, 5 or more properties result in (implicit) `Format-List` formatting).

  - As you can see, creating the XML for the formatting definitions is verbose and cumbersome, even without additional settings, such as column width and alignment.
  - A better, but more elaborate solution would be to package your function in a [*module*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) into whose folder you can place the `*.ps1mxl` file (e.g., `SearchAdUserResult.Format.ps1xml`) and then instruct PowerShell to load the file on module import, via the `FormatsToProcess` key in the [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest) (`*.psd1`) - e.g., `FormatsToProcess = 'SearchAdUserResult.Format.ps1xml'`
- Note that you could alternatively create the `*.ps1mxl` file directly for the `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser` instances that [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser) outputs, but doing so would apply the formatting session-wide, to any command that emits such objects.

```
function Search-ADUser {
  param (
    $Name,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string[]]$Properties = @('Enabled', 'SamAccountName', 'Name', 'emailAddress', 'proxyAddresses')
  )

  # The self-chosen ETS type name.
  $etsTypeName = 'SearchAdUserResult'

  # Create the formatting data on demand.
  if (-not (Get-FormatData -ErrorAction Ignore $etsTypeName)) {

    # Create a temporary file with formatting definitions to pass to 
    # Update-FormatData below.
    $tempFile = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) "$etsTypeName.Format.ps1xml"

    # Define a table view with all 5 properties.
    @"
<Configuration>
<ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>$etsTypeName</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>$etsTypeName</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <TableControl>
        <TableRowEntries>
          <TableRowEntry>
            <TableColumnItems>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Enabled</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>SamAccountName</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>emailAddress</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>proxyAddresses</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
            </TableColumnItems>
          </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
      </TableControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
"@ > $tempFile

    # Load the formatting data into the current session.
    Update-FormatData -AppendPath $tempFile

    # Clean up.
    Remove-Item $tempFile
  }

  # Call Get-ADUser and assign the self-chosen ETS type name to the the output.
  # Note: To test this with a custom-object literal, use the following instead of the Get-ADUser call:
  #      [pscustomobject] @{ Enabled = $true; SamAccountName = 'jdoe'; Name = 'Jane Doe'; emailAddress = 'jdoe@example.org'; proxyAddresses = 'janedoe@example.org' }
  Get-ADUser -Filter ('name -like "*{0}*"' -F $Name) -Properties $Properties | Select-Object $Properties | ForEach-Object {
     $_.pstypenames.Insert(0, $etsTypeName); $_
  }

}
```

You'll then see the desired tabular output based on the format data; e.g.:

```
Enabled SamAccountName Name     emailAddress     proxyAddresses
------- -------------- ----     ------------     --------------
True    jdoe           Jane Doe jdoe@example.org janedoe@example.org
```