# How to require argument be supplied when script is executed

Tags: powershell, arguments, parameter-passing

So this was my script:

```
$ans=Read-Host "What process would you like to query?"
Get-WmiObject win32-process -Filter "name='$ans'" | Format-Table HandleCount,VirtualSize,UserModeTime,KernelModeTime,ProcessID,Name
```

Now I need to create a script which requires the argument be passed when the script is executed.  I'm a little confused on how to do this successfully.  This is what I'm trying to work with:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

`Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name='$1'" | Format-Table HandleCount,VirtualSize,UserModeTime,ProcessID,Name`

Answer (score 3):

To make a parameter *mandatory* (required) in PowerShell, you must use an [*advanced* script or function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced); to create a *script file*, save your code in a `.ps1` file<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string] $Name
)

Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "name='$Name'"
```

Note:

- The code uses [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) instead of `Get-WmiObject`, because the CIM cmdlets superseded the WMI cmdlets in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).
- The [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) call was intentionally omitted, because `Format-*` cmdlets should only ever be used to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*, i.e. never for outputting *data* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).

  - Outputting just *data* means that PowerShell controls in what format your data is displayed; for information on how to control this format, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67991167/45375).

---

<sup>[1] This is enough to make a plain-text file executable *from PowerShell*, without needing to include the `.ps1` extension in the invocation. On Unix-like platforms, you *can* create an executable shell script without a filename extension via a shebang line such as `#!/usr/bin/env pwsh` and `chmod a+x some` that can be called from outside PowerShell as well.</sup>

Comment: Aww man, although I know the consequences of querying using *wmi* cmdlets, I still like to use them. Wasn't aware they went away with them:( they just have so much methods that are really useful! Good to know tho:)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, you can still call methods on the objects that `Get-CimInstance` returns: use [`Invoke-CimMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod). Pragmatically speaking, the `*-Wmi*` cmdlets won't go away, and WMI will continue to _underlie_ CIM on Windows, but it's worth migrating to the `*-Cim*` cmdlets for a consistent experience across local and remote calls, the latter taking advantage of the modern, firewall-friendly CIM remoting transport (using the same infrastructure as PowerShell's own remoting)

Comment: Guess I've never tried to just run those methods that don't show in `Get-Ciminstance`,  but do in gwmi. Will try it using `Invoke-CimMethod`. thx and happy 4th!