# Why is PS Get-ChildItem so difficult

Tags: powershell

I did a ton of reading and searching about a way to have Get-ChildItem return a dir listing in wide format, in alphabetical order, with the number of files and directories in the current directory. Here is a [image](https://puu.sh/HXwv6.PNG) of what I ended up with, but not using GCI.

I ended up writing a small PS file.

```
$bArgs = "--%/c"
$cArgs = "Dir /n/w"
& cmd.exe -ArgumentList $bArgs $cArgs
```

As you can see I ended up using the old cmd.exe and passing the variables I wanted. I made an alias in my PS $Profile to call this script.
Can this not be accomplished in PS v5.1? Thanks for any help or advice for an old noob.

Comment: How about formatting the output like this `Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide -AutoSize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell's for-display formatting differs from `cmd.exe`'s, so if you want the formatting of the latter's internal `dir` command, you'll indeed have to call it via `cmd /c`, via a [*function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) you can place in your `$PROFILE` file (note that [*aliases*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) in PowerShell are merely alternative *names* and can therefore not include baked-in arguments):

```sh
function lss { cmd /c dir /n /w /c $args }
```

Note that you lose a key benefit of PowerShell: the ability to process *rich objects*:

- PowerShell-native commands output rich objects that enable robust programmatic processing; e.g., [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) outputs [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances; the aspect of *for-display* formatting is *decoupled* from the *data* output, and for-display formatting only kicks in when printing to the display (host), or when explicitly requested.

  - For instance, `(Get-ChildItem -File).Name` returns an array of all file names in the current directory.
- By contrast, PowerShell can only use *text* to communicate with external programs, which makes processing cumbersome and brittle, if information must be extracted via *text parsing*.

---

As [Pierre-Alain Vigeant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151488/pierre-alain-vigeant) notes, the following PowerShell command gives you at least *similar* output formatting as your `dir` command, though it lacks the combined-size and bytes-free summary at the bottom:

```sh
Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide -AutoSize
```

To wrap that up in a function, use:

```sh
function lss { Get-ChildItem @args | Format-Wide -Autosize }
```

Note, however, that - due to use of a `Format-*` cmdlet, all of which output objects that are *formatting instructions* rather than *data* - this function's output is also not suited to further programmatic processing.

A proper solution would require you to author *custom formatting data* and associate them with the `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` types, which is nontrivial however.

See the conceptual [about_Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) help topic, [`Export-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-formatdata), [`Update-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-formatdata), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67991167/45375) for a simple example.

Comment: Just wondering why my reply to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) was deleted? Any way, thanks again [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

Comment: @b4iknew I don't know why, but [“thank you” comments are generally discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145551/230282) so many high-rep users and mods will delete it. One should upvote and accept instead

Comment: phuclv is correct, @b4iknew: I flagged your comment as no longer needed, and a moderator removed it as a result. To be clear, I genuinely appreciated your nice feedback; since I perceived your comment as a personal thank-you, I thought it had served its purpose once I had read it.
To future readers it is only comments with technical information that are of interest. Similarly, if I should thank _you_ in a comment in the future or again respond to a thank-you from you, I encourage you to flag that comment as no longer needed as well after reading it - including this one.

Comment: @b4iknew, please also see my update to the answer.